# How much prestige is required before you get the possibility of intruders?

Tags: planetbase

As per the in game assistance regarding Intruders:

> Intruders are criminal elements that will sometimes try to take over your base. They will come in Colonist or Visitor ships once your colony has reached a certain prestige.

Since prestige is a number ranging from 0 to 1000, how much prestige exactly is required before you get the possibility of intruders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get to 100 prestige, intruders will come if you have an active landing pad or star port.

Obviously by 100 prestige you most likely have one of these things, if you want to stop intruders after 100 prestige you can only achieve this by shutting down access to the outside world (disabling the landing pads/star ports).